# Could not resize shared memory segment error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a PostgreSQL 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1) running in a docker container.

I get the following error with some queries:

> could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.860708388" to 536870912 bytes: No space left on device`

system:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5
- memory: 126 GB
- cores: 64

disk usage is fine, as well as quotas.

Postgres settings:

- `work_mem`: 30GB,
- `dynamic_shared_memory_type`: posix
- `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`: 32

Answer (score 1):

Lowering number on `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 8 seems to have fixed the problem in my case.